# "Free to wrong pool at C:/x/perl/lib/XML/Parser/Expat .pm line 432 during global destruction." Is there a way to solve it?

Tags: xml, multithreading, perl, thread-safety

Basically I want to implement multithreading on some code and in that code I use a perl xml library, but I don't really intend to win time on this moment of the code, but I want everything else to work, but it doesn't work even if I don't use this library in the code on which I want to implement threads:

```
use threads;
use xmlparser;

my $file = "project.xml";

#Call the XML Parser
(my $hash_ref,my $exit_state) = xmlparser::ProjectXmlParser($file);

#Define the number of threads
my $num_of_threads = 2;

# use the initThreads subroutine to create an array of threads.
my @threads = initThreads();

# Loop through the array:   
foreach(@threads)
{
    #Tell each thread to perform our 'sub1()' subroutine.
    $_ = threads->create(\&sub1);
}

# This tells the main program to keep running until all threads have finished.
foreach(@threads)
{
    $_->join();
}

####################### SUBROUTINES ############################

sub initThreads
{
    my @initThreads;
    for(my $i = 1;$i<=$num_of_threads;$i++)
    {
        push(@initThreads,$i);
    }
    return @initThreads;
}

sub sub1 {
    sleep(1);
    print "\nIn the thread\n\n";
}
```

Is there a way to eliminate this error or an alternative thread-safe library?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: That error is emitted when a variable created in one thread is freed in a different thread. In this particular case, it's probably because one of the module isn't thread-safe.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need the parser in all the threads? The library is probably not thread safe, so you can't use it from more than one thread. If using it in one thread is enough, don't [use](http://p3rl.org/use) it, but [require](http://p3rl.org/require) it instead in the single thread that needs it.

Comment: Yes, I need the parser in all the threads, because in the real code I use this library in multiple threads  and outside threads too.

Comment: Yes, I understand this, but are there alternatives for this library that are thread-safe or is there a way to lock it in threads so other threads don't use it until the thread that uses it stops to use it?

Comment: Re "*are there alternatives for this library that are thread-safe*", XML::LibXML is an excellent XML parser, and it's thread-safe.

Comment: Check the details under [Thread Support](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::LibXML#THREAD-SUPPORT).